# Div is dim in inspect element of browser, cant retrieve content?

Tags: javascript, html, emacs

I am trying to retrieve data from [this](http://www.ymacs.org/demo/) editor try to inspect the content of that page you will see that the content is inserted in a dim divs and elements.

how can i retrieve this data. i know it is a little messy question but please ask me, and i will try to explain not understandable points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunc(){
     var a = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
     for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         if(a[i].className == 'Ymacs-frame-content'){
              var b = a[i].getElementsByTagName("div");
              for (h = 0; h < b.length; h++) {
                  alert(b[h].innerHTML);
              }
         break;
         }             
     }
}
```

That should do the trick (or something similar)